# Javac cannot infer the type without auxiliary variable

Tags: java, guava, type-inference, java-6

I've faced a java compiler (jdk1.6.0_45) behavior that I can't explain.
Here are the two code snippets — the first one compiles, while the second one does not.
Compiles:

```
Map<String, Collection<MyClass>> result = Maps.newHashMap();

Comparator<? super MyClass> comparator = comparatorProvider.getComparator(*some parameter*);
TreeMultiset<MyClass> multiSet = TreeMultiset.create(comparator);
result.put("blahBlah", multiSet);
```

Doesn't compile:

```
Map<String, Collection<MyClass>> result = Maps.newHashMap();

Comparator<? super MyClass> comparator = comparatorProvider.getComparator(*some parameter*);
result.put("blahBlah", TreeMultiset.create(comparator));
```

Maps and [TreeMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) classes are the part of the Google-Guava libraries.

The second snippet won't compile, giving the following error:

```
put(java.lang.String,java.util.Collection<MyClass>) in java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Collection<MyClass>> cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset<java.lang.Object>)
```

Note that **java.lang.Object** part of the error. So it seems that javac wasn't able to infer the type of TreeMultiset without an explicit "multiset" variable.

Here's the code of the factory method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> TreeMultiset<E> create(
  @Nullable Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
return (comparator == null)
       ? new TreeMultiset<E>((Comparator) Ordering.natural())
       : new TreeMultiset<E>(comparator);
}
```

Any clarity upon this behaviour would be really appreciated.

Even the IDE (Intellij IDEA) gives no errors.

Comment: Crank up your warnings. You have lots of unchecked operations in there which might cause some unexpected results.

Comment: There's not a single unchecked operation — "getComparator()" method is parametrized on the input parameter and type-safe. And the factory method provided for TreeMultiset is a part of Google-Guava library, there's nothing I can do.

Comment: Tagged this with Guava. Someone who has more familiarity with Guava might be able to help better.

Answer (score 3):

Java type inference is not as strong as we would like (compared to, say Scala).  You can give the same type argument without an auxilliary variable:

```
result.put("blahBlah", TreeMultiset.<MyClass>create(comparator));
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can, but I still can't get what's the problem in this particular case. Factory method clearly states — "take the bounded type of the passed comparator and return a TreeMultiset (which implements Collection interface) of that type". In this case, it should always return TreeMultiset<MyClass>. Why am I forced to declare the type explicitly?

Comment: In the first example, the result of the call to "create" is being assigned to a variable TreeMultiset<MyClass>.  Therefore the compiler infers that the only possible type argument is MyClass---that's a pretty easy inference to make.  In the second example, the result of the call to "create" is being passed as an argument to "put", which is itself a generic method.  You and I can see the type argument for put will be Collection<MyClass>, so the only way it will work is if the type argument for create is MyClass, but that is an extra step of logic, which the Java compiler does not implement.